# Calling a particular method using SetInterval

Tags: javascript, dom-events, setinterval

I have a functionality in which a function call must be triggered automatically in a specific time.

(For example: Every week Monday Morning 9 am(EST)).

I know that `setInterval` can trigger a function automatically for a certain time interval, but how do I utilize that function to trigger exactly on Monday Morning 9 am, every week?

Any help is appreciated.

P.S: I forgot to mention the scenario. I need to generate a email report on a weekly basis from Production server for which I need to trigger a method from Javascript to load the contents.

Comment: Are you expecting people to keep their device and browser open 24/7?

Comment: What context is this? Are you running a node server that's constantly up? Or are you trying to do this in the browser?

Comment: No, this occurs in a production server. The scenario is that an email report will be generated on a weekly basis for a django application, I need to trigger a function from Javascript.

Comment: @JThistle I am trying to do this in my browser

Comment: This is implausible if this code is being run in the browser. You need to look into setting up a [crontab](https://linuxhandbook.com/crontab/) on a server that's running 24/7.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to rely on a browser window being open 24/7, you should do this server-side, not client-side.

You mention in a comment you are using django, I'd suggest looking into [django-crontab](https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/), tutorial available [here](https://gutsytechster.wordpress.com/2019/06/24/how-to-setup-a-cron-job-in-django/).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this.